# Ant script with embedded javascript trying to read files

Tags: javascript, ant

I have the following ant build target :

```
<target name="analyze">
    <script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
            importPackage(java.lang);
            var path = project.getProperty("PROJECT_HOME") + "/oms";
            System.out.println("path = " +path);                
        ]]>
    ]]>
    </script>
</target>
```

I'd like to *find* all files in the directory recursively and if they end in .`java` print them out.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an example in the Ant [`script` task docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) that basically does this.  Here's a simplified version:

```
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    importClass(java.io.File);

    fs = project.createDataType("fileset");
    dir = "src";
    fs.setDir( new File( dir ) );
    fs.setIncludes( "**/*.java" );

    // create echo Task via Ant API
    echo = project.createTask("echo");

    // iterate over files found.
    srcFiles = fs.getDirectoryScanner( project ).getIncludedFiles( );
    for ( i = 0; i < srcFiles.length; i++ ) {
        var filename = srcFiles[i];

        // use echo Task via Ant API
        echo.setMessage( filename );
        echo.perform( );
    }]]>
</script>
```

This uses an Ant [FileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) to find the files.  Here an includes rule is set on the fileset so that only `.java` files found are returned by the iterator - saves using string operations on the filenames to discard any other files.

If you need to set exclusion rules you can do so by means of the setExcludes() method of the FileSet class (actually of the [AbstractFileset](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/types/AbstractFileSet.html) class).
See the [docs for patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) to understand a little more about Ant wildcards.

Comment: If I wanted to exclude files in a directory, how would I do that?

Comment: @Amir - I added a note on exclusions.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this with core Ant tasks, without using javascript:

```
  <fileset dir="java" id="java.files.ref">
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
  </fileset>
  <pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="java.files" refid="java.files.ref"/>
  <echo>${java.files}</echo>
```